# group by and show 2 tables linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-5

How can I do a group by for 2 tables and show the article name instead of the id, I have seen that the include does not work

class Article:

```
 public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome obbligatorio")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name_article { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Quantità")]
    public int? Quantity_article { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Display(Name = "Descrizione")]
    public string Description_article { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Immagine")]
    public string Picture_article { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nome categoria")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ArticleOrder> ArticleOrders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
```

Class Cart

```
 public int CartId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity_cart { get; set; }
    //Dettaglio categorie
    [Display(Name = "Data creazione")]
    public DateTime? CreatedAt_cart { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Data ultima modifica")]
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt_cart { get; set; }

    //navigazione carrello
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Query in controller:

```
List<Cart> cart = _context.Carts
        .Include(a => a.Article)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ArticleId)
        .Select(t => new Cart {ArticleId = t.Key, Quantity_cart = t.Sum(u => u.Quantity_cart)}).ToList();

        return View(cart);
```

View:

@model IEnumerable<Progetto_Prosemag.Models.Cart>

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr style="background-color: #11ffee00;">
            <td class="fontprimary textcenter" style="width: 280px; height: 170px; overflow-wrap: break-word ">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Article.Name_article)
            </td>
            <td class="fontsecondary textcenter" style="width: 280px; height: 170px; overflow-wrap: break-word">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity_cart)
            </td>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: MAybe not the only problem, but you aren't selecting the article properties in your query, only the ID and total quantity:  `.Select(t => new Cart {ArticleId = t.Key, Quantity_cart = t.Sum(u => u.Quantity_cart)})`

Comment: `Include` do not work and should not work with `GroupBy`. How do you plan to get Article Name, in which property?

Comment: I would need to extract the article name from the article table in the group by query how can I do?